# Back-propagation code

Tags: javascript, neural-network

So I wrote this code a while ago, but i'm trying to optimize my code. Is there anything that I should definitely change here to save memory/time? 
The code checks if the neuron is an output or hidden/input neuron, or a constant neuron (the last should stay unaltered).

- the input is a decimal, decimal and array with decimals.
- this.error is a dictionary containing error values
- this.connections contains in, out, and self. Which all are arrays of connections
- connection.xtrace is a dictionary in the form of `{nodes: [], values : []}`, nodes are instances and values are decimals

Here is the code:

```
  propagate: function(rate, momentum, target) {
    // Error accumulator
    var error = 0;

    momentum = momentum || 0;

    // Output nodes get their error from the enviroment
    if (this.type == 'output'){
      this.error.responsibility = this.error.projected = target - this.activation;
    } else { // the rest of the nodes compute their error responsibilities by backpropagation
      // error responsibilities from all the connections projected from this node
      for (var connection in this.connections.out) {
        var connection = this.connections.out[connection];
        var node = connection.to;
        // Eq. 21
        error += node.error.responsibility * connection.weight * connection.gain;
      }

      // Projected error responsibility
      this.error.projected = this.derivative * error;

      // Error responsibilities from all connections gated by this neuron
      error = 0;

      for(var conn in this.connections.gated){
        conn = this.connections.gated[conn];
        var node = conn.to;
        var influence = node.connections.self.gater == this ? node.old : 0;

        influence += conn.weight * conn.from.activation;
        error += node.error.responsibility * influence;
      }

      // Gated error responsibility
      this.error.gated = this.derivative * error;

      // Error responsibility
      this.error.responsibility = this.error.projected + this.error.gated;
    }

    if(this.type == 'constant') return;

    // Learning rate
    rate = rate || .3;

    // Adjust all the node's incoming connections
    for (var connection in this.connections.in) {
      var connection = this.connections.in[connection];

      var gradient = this.error.projected * connection.elegibility;

      for(var i = 0; i < connection.xtrace.nodes.length; i++){
        var node = connection.xtrace.nodes[i];
        var value = connection.xtrace.values[i];
        gradient += node.error.responsibility * value;
      }

      var deltaWeight = rate * gradient * this.mask + momentum * connection.previousDeltaWeight;

      connection.weight += deltaWeight;

      connection.previousDeltaWeight = deltaWeight;
    }

    // Adjust bias
    this.bias += rate * this.error.responsibility;
  },
```